# Flex: Looking for design pattern to display busy cursor while my app is "busy"

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a Flex 4 app that now and then needs to do a lot of processing, which causes a user to wait a few seconds for it to complete. I know Flex allows one to set and remove busy cursors via the cursor manager. I'm using it as follows:

```
CursorManager.setBusyCursor();    // add busy cursor
// execute lengthy processing here; e.g. switch to a new screen with a lot of layout
CursorManager.removeBusyCursor(); // remove busy cursor
```

However, in practice, for certain situations, the busy cursor doesn't display, or, if it displays, it displays just before it gets removed (if you blink you'd miss it). The idea is to have the busy cursor display while the lengthly processing occurs, not for a fraction of a second after it completes.

So, I'm wondering if there's a design pattern I can use to make sure the busy cursor is always displayed BEFORE executing the lengthly processing steps. For example, these processing steps could be: (1) transitioning to a new screen that must be built, which has a complex layout, or (2) creating a chart that takes a long time to render, etc.

I suspect anyone designing in Flex has run into this at one time or another. Is there a general design pattern one can use, or is it a unique adventure each time to figure out where exactly to execute the busy cursor so that it displays at the right moment in time? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Both your examples our about rendering, which should be delegated by the framework to the next render cycle. However, since displaying another cursor is also a rendering task, that might explain why both jobs are fighting to be executed first on that next cycle. Have you tried initiating your lengthy operation using the [callLater()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#callLater%28%29) method?

Comment: Thanks RIAstar, I've never used callLater(). Could you give an example how it could be used in this context?

Comment: Well, you just `callLater(myLengthyOperation)` or perhaps `callLater(myLengthyOperation, anArgumentForMyLengthyOperation)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that any kind of "lengthy processing" will freeze the UI, so that it will not get a chance to update the screen - and therefore not show any cursor changes prior to starting the calculation.

There are a couple of thing you can do, but before we get into details: Of course it would be best to keep freezes from happening in the first place! You can do this in one of two ways: Change your calculations in such a way that you either optimize  your algorithms enough so that they can complete faster than the current frame rate, or break down longer calculations into smaller chunks, thus "spreading" resource intensive loops across multiple frames - and allow the screen to update in between. You can use [workers](http://esdot.ca/site/2012/intro-to-as3-workers-hello-world) for that in the current FP version, or [pseudo threads](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1427) in older ones.

For quick results, just delay the heavy process by 100ms using `setTimeout`, *after* changing the cursor.  That way, the screen can update before the calculations start.

Comment: Yes, the UI does appear frozen -- I'm using a Mac and when the lengthy processes execute, the cursor disappears, and after a second or two, I get the Mac's spinning color wheel indicating system resources are busy, then a few seconds later the app comes to life, things update and it's done. I need a mechanism to indicate to the user to wait while the app runs. I like the `setTimeout` idea as a quick approach. Not sure how I can break up my math computations or screen layout creation -- what does Flex consider "one chunk" as you put it (where's the dividing line; or how to break up steps)?

Comment: Mostly, these freezes happen when you process a large number of items, for example when creating lists to display on the screen. You will typically have a for- or while loop, which can be broken down (i.e. iterate items 1-20, wait for screen refresh, then iterate 21-40, etc.).  Take a look at the pseudo thread article - it takes up that approach and makes a pattern out of it.

Comment: Do you use a timer to wait for a screen refresh, or is there an event to listen for, etc?

Comment: In the pseudo thread pattern, it does calculation for one item, measures how long that takes, then uses that data to estimate how many items can be calculated before the next screen refresh.  But you can simplify that part if you do a little math: 1000 / frame rate is the time until the next frame. Set a timer, count how many items you've processed in between, and then just take a couple less items as your default chunk size.

Comment: Then, you can use Event.ENTER_FRAME as your loop.

Comment: Wouldn't the processing time depend on the user's machine (e.g. CPU speed, graphics processor, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, certainly. That is why the pseudo thread pattern uses an actual measurement to determine the number of items to process. The short cut also works, as long as you allow some tolerance, though.

Comment: Thanks weltraumpirat, Unfortunately the lengthy processing is due to Flex creating and laying out components in a tab, so I'm not sure how to implement the `setTimeout` short cut in this scenario. I started another thread for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743942/flex-how-to-call-titlewindow-when-changing-tab-before-tabs-ui-components-are

Comment: What's the significance of 100ms for `setTimeout`? How do we know that 100 ms is sufficient across all clients to guarantee an update (e.g. is there variability across client machines that needs to be accounted for with extra margin)?

Comment: It's enough to allow the frame loop to run, even at the standard rate: 1000ms/12 fps == 83,3 ms.

Comment: Thanks weltraumpirat, I've implemented somewhat of a solution based on your `setTimeout()` comment, noted in UPDATE 1 here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743942/flex-how-to-call-titlewindow-when-changing-tab-before-tabs-ui-components-are).